# Why "agoraphobia" not "agorophobia"?

Tags: morphology, greek, word-formation

Greek compounds are usually made by combining the roots of two nouns and inserting a linking thematic vowel when it would result in a sequence of two consonants. The vowel is usually -o-, so we have e.g.

> claustr-o-phob-ia, electr-o-magnet-ism, ec-o-nom-y, hor-o-scope

When the second root starts with a vowel, the linking vowel *-o-* is not needed, so we have

> mis-o-gyn-y

but

> mis-anthrop-y, mis-andr-y.

But why is "agoraphobia" with an *-a-*? It is made from *agora* and *phobia*, so one would expect

> *agor-o-phob-ia. (but this is not the case)

And, are there more such words that use *-a-* not *-o-*?

Comment: This is a really good question. Why the votes to close?

Comment: If I may, there is a proposal to create a Greek Language stackexchange, you can support it by adding your question as an example and/or upvoting the other questions: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101509/greek-language

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [ELU](http://elu.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It seems related to historical linguistics and morphophonology, so I think it can stay on this site.

Comment: @nyg I agree this should go in the Greek stackexchange proposal.

Comment: *Phobia* means *fear*, and everybody's afraid of math, and it is also well-known that Pythagoras -not Pythagoros- was a male Greek mathematician (despite the fact that Greek male names usually do end in -*os*, just as Latin ones end in -*us*), which is why, eventually, *Pythagoraphobia* came to mean *fear of math*, but, since it was quite a mouthful, it later got shortened to simply *agoraphobia*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The connecting vowel in Ancient Greek compounds depends on the declension of the first noun: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0007%3Apart%3D3%3Achapter%3D24

- If the first noun is first declension, the connecting vowel was originally -ā- : *agor-ā-nomos* 'market clerk', *nik-ē-phoros* 'bringing victory' (-ē- is the Ionic for -ā-)
- If the first noun is second declension, the connecting vowel was originally -o-: *log-o-graphos* 'speech-writer'
- If the first noun is third declension, and the stem already ends in a vowel, leave it alone, e.g. *ichty-bolos* 'catching fish'; otherwise, add -o-, e.g. *sōmat-o-phylax* 'bodyguard'

The selection of vowels is not random of course: first declension nouns have inflections based on -ā-, and second declension nouns have inflections based on -o-.

This rule has been massively messed up by analogy though: in Ancient Greek, there are plenty of first declension nouns with -o- (*dik-o-graphos* 'writer of legal speeches'), and second and third declension nouns with -ā- (*elaphē-bolos* 'deer-shooting'). The -o- linking vowel eventually prevailed, and is the only one used in Modern Greek.

In the case of *agoraphobia*, the precedent in Ancient Greek was that *agora* compounds, like *agorānomos*, always had -ā- as the connecting vowel. The new coinage preserved that precedent.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the vowel used to link the two words depends on the first one. For example, claustrophobia uses an -o- because it comes from the Latin "claustrum", same with electromagnetism, from Latin "electrum". In the case of misogyny, the Greek word involved is "misos", so an -o- is used, but since the root for agoraphobia is "agora", the -a- is preserved. Another example is triskaidekaphobia, the fear of the number thirteen, which comes from the Greek "triskaideka", which ends in "a". Basically, if it already ends in "a", there's no reason to change it to an "o" when connecting it to another word.

Comment: Suggestion: mention that many Latin words in -us and -um actually have -o- as their stem vowel (such as *claustrum*), since otherwise *claustrum* → *claustro-* is non-obvious?

Comment: I thought about this, but this is not true for just any word ending in -ā or -ē in Greek. Words like thalassa (sea) and, definitely, psūchē, hōrã, limnē (lake) end in -a, but they have only thalasso-, psycho-, horo-, and limno-. In fact afaik nearly all such Greek words use -o-. So while I really like this idea, I feel we need to zero in on just exactly what words do have -a as *a part of its root*, not a really removable suffix like an inflection suffix.

Comment: I've so far only found two other words that preserve -a in some of its compounds, timē (honor) and skiā (shadow). timē has two such compounds, tima-ochos (honor-having) and tima-oros (>timōros, "avenging"; 2nd element related to "see"), but it has tim-o-krat-iā (timocracy). For skiā, we have the English words sciamachy and sciaphobia, though the second has an alternative form sciophobia.

Comment: Triskaidekaphobia is a great and interesting example, but I feel there is really no other possible form. As it goes, *tris kai deka* is "three and ten", i.e. "thirteen". The -a in *deka* is just part of the word, as *deka* (ten) is not declinable and has the only form *deka*. So when one makes a "triskaideka phobia", they can't really detach -a and add -o- because that -a is not morphologically divisible, but the (last) vowel in the second and last syllable of the morpheme "ten", or the last phoneme thereof.