# Rules to constructing a proper compound noun in Ancient Greek

Tags: greek, compounds, ancient

I am currently in the process of translating a text from one language into another, and the original uses a compound noun that can either be translated into English as *"fly-eating"* (losing the original's charm) or a fancy quasi-medical term involving "-phagia". I have tried searching for rules regarding Ancient Greek compound nouns' formation but could not unearth a definite algorithm.

The word for *"fly"* would be [myia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BC%CF%85%E1%BF%96%CE%B1#Ancient_Greek) and [-phagia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-phagy#English) could be appended at the end to signify *"eating"*. I would appreciate it if someone with better knowledge of Ancient Greek could help me combine the two together, and I would love to see some scholarly articles on this topic. Surely there are some rules that medical scientists and jurisprudents follow when giving names to new terms?

Comment: I am by no means an expert, so this isn't an answer, but my impression is that "linking o" is usual in compounds formed in the present day, so I would guess "myiophagy". However, a possible issue with this (I don't know if it's really a problem) is that I think it would be a homophone with *myophagy* "muscle-eating". I wanted to learn the answer to this question after encountering the word "[trypophobia](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/413092/77227)"

Comment: "[my(i)ophily](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/myophily)" is apparently attested enough to get into the Collins dictionary. I don't know why the "i "can be omitted: it might be just an English spelling simplification, or it might be related to some kind of dialectal variation in Greek (the [Liddell and Scott dictionary of Greek](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dmui%3Da1) says *μῦα* ("mya") existed as an Attic variant of *μυῖα* ("myia"))

Comment: @sumelic, thank you, that answers my question! Would you mind submitting an answer with the links you've shared, or should I do so myself? I would personally leave the "i" in, as the word might otherwise get confused with words sharing their root with [myopia](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/myopia). Upd: or perhaps we should wait for an expert, since we were both confused by _myophagy_, _myopia_ and the like.

Comment: Well, the question has two close votes, so I'm not sure if I should answer it because it seems some people think it is off-topic here (and I can see the argument for that, as it is rather language-specific). I would recommend re-posting the question on http://latin.stackexchange.com, which despite the name does also currently accept questions about Ancient Greek. There are some people on that site who have actual expertise, unlike me, and who might post an answer (although I can't promise that).

Comment: If you ask there and no expert steps up, I will post an answer and hopefully the experts will at least give feedback on it by voting and comments

Comment: @sumelic, thank you, I didn't notice that. I was considering posting it on Latin, but I wasn't really sure. It is quite a shame there is no stackexchange site dedicated to Greek and Ancient Greek. I shall follow your advice, good sir. Thank you so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69197/discussion-between-pyromonk-and-sumelic).

Comment: Nowadays, [latin.se] accepts questions on Classical Greek and would be the right venue for this kind of question.

Comment: @SirCornflakes, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for the formation of compounds are explained in the more elaborate Greek grammars, but I think you are asking about this specific word. In Classical Greek there are quite a large number of compounds from μυιο- or μυο-, as you can see here:

- [μυιο-](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/search3t?dbname=LSJ&dgdivhead=%CE%BC%CF%85%CE%B9%CE%BF*&orthmode=unaccented)
- [μυο-](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/search3t?dbname=LSJ&dgdivhead=%CE%BC%CF%85%CE%BF*&orthmode=unaccented)

Click on the individual words for their meaning. Myo- or myiophagia would be a correctly formed compound and there is theoretically no reason why you should not be able to use it in the more bookish register of English.

Comment: Both links return "No objects found." I am not sure if that's my stupidity at play or lack of attention. If you could refer to specific "elaborate Greek grammars", that would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with the link. Maybe some computer expert can help.

Comment: For compound nouns look at the last section (pp. 352 sqq.) of Buck’s “Comparative grammar of Greek and Latin”, for example.

Comment: I am a "computer expert", so if I can't help myself, it's my fault. Maybe I should attempt it in a more sober and collected state. I have taken a look at [Buck's work](https://ia902507.us.archive.org/21/items/BuckComparativeGrammer/CGL.pdf) but couldn't come to any conclusions looking at pages 352 and after. I might have to read the whole book, but that will take a while.

Comment: Ran a search on the perseus site. _μυιο_ does indeed return fly-related words and _μυο_ mostly returns muscle-related ones. I will have to take a look at the book you've recommended to see if there is an algorithm for constructing compounds. I have not touched ancient philology that deeply for about 10 years, so that will be quite a journey.

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as accepted, as my initial question doesn't quite fit the scope of this StackExchange, and you have more than well answered the part about flies, providing links to resources that might help. I will try to seek out further information over at Latin. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

See [Why "agoraphobia" not "agorophobia"?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/why-agoraphobia-not-agorophobia/22943#22943)

myia is a first declension noun, so *originally* in Greek the correct answer was *myiaphagia*, just as *agoraphobia* is actually the correct form, historically. But the -o- of the second declension extended to first declension nouns in compounds very very early—so early that -a- compounds are the archaic exception in Classical Greek, rather than the rule. The normally expected connective is indeed -o-, and that's what fdb's answer (https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/26458/17064) reports.